# Ajax success() function does not work inside jQuery on function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a jquery code with ajax function to get data form database on dropdown change.

But the ajax function looks like it doesn't executed and when I inspect the code using chrome browser it doesn't give any error messages I tried to alert some data on change function and it works but I don't get any result or data inside success function.

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#prov_id').on('change', function() {
    alert($('#prov_id').val());
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ajax_queries.php',
      data: {
        request: 'get_states',
        prov_id: $('#prov_id').val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

this alert is work

```
alert($('#prov_id').val());
```

but this is doesn't

```
success: function(data){
  alert(data);
}
```

any help ?

Comment: Try adding an error handler as well.

Comment: Also check what your developer tools network tab says. Was the request launched? With what status it finished?

Answer (score 0):

set `dataType:'json'` in your ajax request :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#prov_id').on('change',function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ajax_queries.php',
      dataType:'json',
      data: {request:'get_states',prov_id:$('#prov_id').val()},
      success: function(data){
          alert(data);
      },
      error:function(){
       alert('Error :(');
      }    
    });
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Why should `dataType:'json'` solve the problem? If the request was success full then the `alert` should still work. So if you think this will solve the problem, then please add an explanation why.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function(ht) {
    alert( ht );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

Comment: You changed the request type from `POST` to `GET`, changed the URL and removed the data that should be passed. Is that required to solve the problem or why did you do that? What part of you code solves the problem and why?

Comment: $.ajax( "ajax_queries.php" )
  .done(function(ht) {
    alert( 1 );    
  })                 give u alert?

Answer (score -1):

You should store data into variable first, before passing it to ajax.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#prov_id').on('change',function(){
    var prov_id = $('#prov_id').val();
    alert(prov_id);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ajax_queries.php',
      data: {request:'get_states',prov_id:prov_id},
      success: function(data){
          alert(data);

      }

        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why should it be relevant to store the data in a variable before passing it to ajax? What difference would it make in the given code?